# Is there a Chrome equivalent for Firefox's multi-account container extension?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, multi-account-containers

I just found out about Firefox's multi-account container extension.  For those unfamiliar, this is a good overview...https://youtu.be/Gy7lyvAfOSw.

It seems like a fantastic solution for being able to be logged into the same account, e.g. your personal account and business account with the same bank, at the same time without having to constantly sign out of one account and sign back into the other account.

Are folks aware of an equivalent option for Chrome?  (I sometimes use incognito windows for this sort of thing, but it's an unsatisfactory solution as you need to sign back in every time.)

Comment: The firefox container extension can't be replaced by any other extensions. I have a few suggestions for other browsers

1- MultiLogin : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi

2- SessionBox : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sessionbox-multi-login-to/megbklhjamjbcafknkgmokldgolkdfig/related

Comment: Profiles feature maybe an workaround https://www.chromium.org/developers/creating-and-using-profiles/

Answer (score 18):

There is SessionBox, but it does not have the exact same features, I am afraid.
"Firefox Multi-Account Containers" is the only reason why I use Firefox.

Comment: Edid queue is full, so here the link to SessionBox! https://sessionbox.io/discover

Comment: The SessionBox Free plan just stopped working for me. I think it became fully premium: https://sessionbox.io/plans/

Comment: This one didn't work for me with Teams. I ended up setting-up two Chrome profiles (no extension required, but you may have to replicate parameters between the two).

Comment: Still, firefox containers leave much to imagination. A pain in the ass to use.

Answer (score 18):

I recommend [Switch Multi-Account Login](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multilogin/ijfgglilaeakmoilplpcjcgjaoleopfi) for Chrome/Chromium. It's the best alternative have found.

Comment: Here the official website https://multilogin.top

Comment: Links not working...

Comment: Gmail site doesn't work when installed this extension. so removed it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. When I click it, I'm still logged-in in Teams.

Comment: This has very limited feature set compared to "Firefox Multi-Account Containers" - cannot define multiple sets of named containers that you can hide and recall as desired...

Answer (score 14):

As for 2023, there's no equivalent of FF's multi-containers in Brave/Chrome.

### Vote for this feature on Brave

But you can spread the word and vote for this feature here:
https://community.brave.com/t/equivalent-of-multi-account-containers-or-temporary-containers-extension-ff/135573

### Some (bad) alternatives:

- **Plugins:** there are many plugins aimed for this, but IMO they are all bad. First, I wouldn't trust a random developer to access all my browser's data (URLs, cookies, sessions, etc). Second, these plugins are not practical as FF's containers. Too many clicks to do anything - it's almost as bad, or even worse than opening a second browser.
- **Chrome's profiles**: The "profiles" are not for privacy or multi-session. It's for people sharing the same browser not mess with Google's tracking causing financial loss to Google. It's aimed to produce better quality ads. It's bad for privacy and it's less practical than using a second browser or opening a private window.

Comment: Additionally, Chrome profiles require redoing browser settings, extension installations and extension settings. Thanks